# Get $LSB_JOBID on execution host

Tags: lsf

I'm having trouble to access the JOB-ID of an submitted, non-interactive job within that job. When using an interactive job, I can access the job-id via `$LSB_JOBID`. But that variable is not propagated to the execution-host.
However, different sources state, that LSB_JOBID is [propagated](http://wwwuser.gwdg.de/%7Eparallel/lsf_doc/ref_6.0/O_envars.html) and others state that it [isn't](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/sierra/man/bsub.txt) (look for -env). Are there any solutions to this? My system creates temp-directories for each job which can be accessed via the jobid which is why I definitely need it within the job.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

LSB_JOBID is set for non interactive jobs. Have you asked your cluster admin about this? There are a few LSF features that could override the default behaviour, like esub, job starter, or eexec.

Comment: No, I haven't asked yet, I wanted to exclude an error from my side before doing that.